# Cannot resolve MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION

Tags: java, android, methods, gps

In the following code I can not resolve  MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION on line number 11 inside the if block, I checked alll the possible things and also compile google play service in the dependencies but it cannot resolved :| 
what should I do ? 
 I am actually tracking the user's location at every 5 mins and display it.
The error is

> Error:(60, 41) error: cannot find symbol variable MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION

Can anyone help me out ?

```
public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        if ( ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION )
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED )
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions( this, new String[]
                    {  android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                    },
                    LocationServices.MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION
            );
            Toast.makeText(GPSTracker.this, "open gps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        Log.i("ok", "outside IF location");
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                10000,   // 3 sec
                10, this);
        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
            Toast.makeText(GPSTracker.this, "open it", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}
```

Comment: Please paste your code here.

Comment: what  error u facing can you post it

Comment: @YounasBangash Error:(60, 41) error: cannot find symbol variable MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION

Comment: is LocationServices your own class? Or the framework class? Are you importing correctly?

Comment: @BryanDunlap Location Srrvices is not my class and yes i am impoting properly 
btw thanks for your help

Comment: Im confused why you are trying to get that constant from location services, I am pretty sure nothing like that exists in there and thereby it isn't needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just checking if you did not mean MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION instead of MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION